# Collision paradox

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

Suppose an insect travelling south at some velocity, collides with a train travelling north at some other (opposite) velocity.

The insect hits the front of the train, where it splats to an unfortunate demise. However, at some point during the impact, surely the insect - upon becoming affixed to the front of the train - has to reverse its direction in order to continue in the same direction and speed as the train (which never stops or slows, and is unaffected by the event).

If so, doesn't this also mean that at some instant(s) in time the insect is travelling at 0mph (as it transitions from travelling south to north), while it is continually 'connected' to the train, which never stops?

How is this possible, or where am I going wrong with this logic?

**edit:**

I would like to revise the question to ask specifically about each atom/particle(/whatever) as it hits the train; what happens at this scale? Do we get squishy quarks? :)

Comment: What's the last thing that goes through this insect's mind as it collides with the train?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the insect does actually travel at 0mph when it reverses direction. The critical aspect that you are missing is that the time that it is not moving is infinitely short. Actually, I would think that the head stops, then the thorax and finally the tail as it is squished up against the train.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but the term 'infinitely short' here feels a bit like it avoids the crux of the problem without providing any real explanation. Also, perhaps I should revise the question to ask: what happens to each atom (or largest non-deformable element) of the insect as they collide; how could the atoms deform?

Comment: @Panjo Even though we can time events in the order of nonoseconds, the time that the insect (or constituent atom) is stationary is even shorter. It's the same in baseball when the batter hits the ball. You know the ball reverses direction and must stop, but it is so fast, even the fastest series of images can't measure the time (you should see the deformation of the ball).

Comment: Hi @LDC3, I understand the concept, but still, during that period of time - no matter how short - doesn't the paradox still exist (the observation of the event is irrelevant)? The physics which occur during this period of time is the exact subject of this question.

Comment: @Panjo I don't see it as a paradox since I understand the motion involved. An atom (moving) strikes a collection of other atoms (stationary in our frame of reference). The boundary of the atom is not rigid (like a rubber ball). All the atoms deform to collect the kinetic energy. Most of the energy is returned to the atom in moving it in the opposite direction. It would move away at some speed except that the other atoms in the moving object have a strong attraction for that atom and the group stays together.

Comment: Good comment. I now wonder if the 'problem' here is indeed due to the reference frame of the observer. If this is considered as a ball bouncing on the ground (I'm supposing this is analogous when taking frames of reference in to consideration), at the point of impact the ball does reach 0mph, but only as far as the earth and ball are concerned. Following newtonian laws, the impact does cause the earth to decelerate (albeit by a very small amount), providing the 'breathing room' needed for the ball to decelerate in a finite time. The idea of 0mph for the observer is the flaw here?

Answer (score 2):

Both the insect and the train window are deformable.  Microscopically so, but deformable nonetheless.  Because of that fact, the insect slows continuously to zero, reverses direction, and then speeds up in the direction the train is going.  To our human perception this happens imperceptibly fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - please see the comment to LDC3's answer (what happens to each atom (or largest non-deformable element) of the insect as it collides?)

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting paradox. But it must have a solution, so let's try and find something that is adequate to our everyday experience: the train must not, obviously, stop.
I think the reason why this problem is startling at first is that it refers to an insect. When we think of an insect, we think of something with almost only two dimensions. But an insect, even a small one, has volume. 
So, if, instead of an insect, we imagine a cube, it is easier to imagine a scenario where the front of the cube (the one that faces the train) first approaches the train and then gets squeezed and deformed by the front of the train, while the other side of the cube is, for a very short period of time, at rest.
This is analogous to what happens with the insect.

Answer (score 0):

I propose my solution to this paradox. Well let us assume the insect is travelling at velocity $v$ and train travelling towards the insect at speed $v_1$ (not in insects frame of reference, but trains frame of reference).

That said, now the insect hits the train and as a result will decelerate at an finite amount of time $t$ as it is impossible to decelerate at $0$ seconds (as soon as insect is in contact with train) in ANY frame of reference because it would imply $\infty$ energy because of the equation of acceleration\deceleration $\frac{(0 - v)}{0}$ for example let us take $v$ to be $10$ m/s therefore it gives us an answer of $\infty$ as $\frac{-10}{0} = \infty$ and any physicist recognizes if an $\infty$ arises in any arbitrary system, there is an flaw in design of system and I used this and deduced if such a case exists conservation laws (energy conservation in specific) are broken with our pre-existing knowledge of basic physics we can deduce that the insect must have decelerated at some finite amount of time that is $t\ne 0$ that said we can safely say such an environment cannot exist. This suggests either the train has deformed very slightly or the insect has or a bit of both in order to obey the elegant conservation laws of the universe.

That mathematical proof, suggests this thought experiment is not valid in real-world.

Now, keep that in mind such a design of a train may be impossible as Theory of Relativity tells us that the observer if changes his velocity in respect to the train the train may look as if it is slowing-down or speeding-up  depending on the observers change in velocity in respect to the frame of reference, so we can say such a object cannot exist as you have clearly stated the train may not be changed in velocity yet in observers frame of reference it has which shows an problem with the "ideal" conditions set in your thought experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, @RohanVijjhalwar. I was not suggesting the train could not be stopped or slowed, rather I made the assumption it would not. The train and insect could be interchanged with a constantly moving massive mass, colliding with a single particle with a relatively insignificant mass. What would happen here? Even if the big mass was affected, it would not stop pushing or stop entirely at any point. How would the velocity change of the particle be described?

Comment: Actually think of the particle, again as pushing back upon the train to give it time to decelerate from its velocity $v$, or it will break into quark-gluon plasma like in LHC. This is why it is so difficult to synthesize different elements because if the particle hits the atom that is near enough to be synthesizing too hard, it may cause it to "smash" up. Similarly, either the particle will hit it and get destroyed into sub-atomic junk or it will simple move the train slightly back either the window or the railing and will decelerate and so will stop pushing for a moment due to deformation

Comment: It may sound impossible but if you had a sensitive enough detector and a time-keeping device you will see the particle simply given time to stop due to deformation. To make it easier let me give you an analogy, take a latex piece and move the latex and your finger towards each other and you will notice your finger will push the latex back and is stretched as the latex is also moving forward and your finger in other, and this exact analogy would happen in your thought experiment. This is negligible but it still happens and this solves your problem.